# Dúvida ao realizar SQL com Eloquent do Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Estou com um `bug` que não sei o motivo de tal.

Tenho em meu `controller` o seguinte `Eloquent`:

```
$balances = BankUser::select(DB::raw('SUM(balance) AS total, 
          created_at, DATE(created_at) AS total_at'))
    ->whereYear('created_at', $year)->whereMonth('created_at', $month)
    >groupBy('total_at')->get();
```

Que está me gerando o seguinte erro:

> `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'db_develop.account_bank_user.created_at' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select SUM(balance) AS total, created_at, DATE(created_at) AS total_at from`ut_banks_user`where year(created_at) = 2018 and month(created_at) = 12 group by total_at)`

Porém se eu copio o `SQL` que está sendo gerado:

> `select SUM(balance) AS total, created_at, DATE(created_at) AS total_at from`account_bank_user`where year(`created_at`) = 2018 and month(`created_at`) = 12 group by`total_at``

E executo em meu PHPMyAdmin ele consulta e trás os registros, o que está faltando no código?

Comment: Qual versão do seu Laravel e qual banco de dados? Consegue me mandar como está configurado o seu `config/database.php`

Comment: Você tem que adicionar o `created_at` no group by

Comment: Dá uma olhada nas respostas dessa [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603075/laravel-eloquent-get-results-grouped-by-days)

Comment: Este código esta dentro de um for?

Answer (score 3):

De acordo com as respostas dessa [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603075/laravel-eloquent-get-results-grouped-by-days) que achei muito interessante, peguei uma das respostas mais simples

```
$balances = 
  BankUser::select(DB::raw('SUM(balance) AS total,created_at, DATE(created_at) AS total_at'))
                    ->whereYear('created_at', $year)->whereMonth('created_at', $month)
                    ->groupBy(DB::raw('Date(created_at)')->get();
```

Note o `groupBy` dentro usa o `DB::raw()`

Answer (score 2):

To muito puto mas feliz por ter arrumado hahaha, obrigado pelas dicas, mas solucionei de um jeito tão idiota que ainda não caiu a ficha.

```
$balances = BankUser::select(DB::raw('SUM(balance) AS total, DATE(created_at) AS total_at'))
    ->whereYear('created_at', $year)->whereMonth('created_at', $month)
    ->groupBy('total_at')->get();
```

Ou seja, apenas removi do select o primeiro `created_at`